# How to assign a delegate of a submenu of the MasterViewController in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uisplitviewcontroller

I am having a DetailViewController which is a delegate of a submenu that has not been pushed yet at the beginning of the app launch. Here I wonder where is the best place to assign the delegate property to the ViewController.

This is what I did at the AppDelegates.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        dataController = DataController()

        let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
        splitViewController.delegate = self

        let detailNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
        detailNavigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
        let mainVC = detailNavigationController.topViewController as! MainViewController
        mainVC.dataController = dataController

        let masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController
        let mainMenuVC = masterNavigationController.topViewController as! MainMenuViewController
        mainMenuVC.dataController = dataController

        self.storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let nationsMenuVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NationsMenuViewController") as! NationsMenuViewController
        nationsMenuVC.delegate = mainVC

        return true
    }
```

and the submenu (NationsMenuVC) has this:

```
protocol NationsMenuViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func nationSelected(nation: City?)
}

class NationsMenuViewController: UITableViewController {

    var nations:[City] = []
    var moc: NSManagedObjectContext!
    weak var delegate: NationsMenuViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
.
.
.

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCity = self.nations[indexPath.row]
    self.delegate?.nationSelected(selectedCity)
    print("clicked at \(selectedCity.name)")
}

}
```

And I did implement the delegate protocol in my detail viewcontroller (MainVC), but the function did not trigger. I wonder if it's because the delegate property was assign as weak at the app launching, and since it did not have any referral from the main menu yet (since user hasn't actually click it at the master viewcontroller level yet), the delegate link might have already been dismissed from the memory?

In this scenario, where would be the best place to declare the delegations of the viewcontroller that hasn't been loaded yet?

```
extension MainViewController: NationsMenuViewControllerDelegate {
    func nationSelected(nation: City?) {
        if let selectedCity = nation {
            let coor:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: selectedCity.latitude!.doubleValue, longitude: selectedCity.longitude!.doubleValue)
            let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 8.0, longitudeDelta: 8.0)
            let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coor, span: span)
            self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            print("selected \(selectedCity.name)")
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that the nationsMenuVC that you created in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  is never used and hence gets immediately de allocated.  You can set up the delegate in the viewDidLoad of NationsMenuViewController.   You might wonder how to access the mainVC inside the viewDidLoad of NationsMenuViewController.  You can create a function in AppDelegate to vend this out

```
 func  mainVC() -> MainViewController{

    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController


            let detailNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController

       let mainVC = detailNavigationController.topViewController as! MainViewController
      return mainVC

    }
```

Now you can call this inside the viewDidLoad of NationsMenuViewController and set up the delegate:

```
self.delegate  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate. mainVC()
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks Shripada, but can you just call self.window! out of the blue to get the UISplitViewController just like that?

    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController

Comment: Nevermind, I just did this:

    self.window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow